# Permutations with repetitions - Non-anagram algorithm

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, anagram

**AIM:** I am trying to find the maximum length of a list comprising non-anagrams, of length N, each anagram-word consisting of a combination of 3 letters: 'A's, 'B's or 'C's.

For example, if N = 5: [AAAAA, AAAAB, ..., AABBC, ..., BABAA, ..., CCCCC].

To clarify, since AAAAB is an anagram of AABAA and vice versa, they're discounted from the output list.

---

**MY PROBLEM:** Firstly, I would like to know how to produce all 3^5 permutations.
My attempt:

```
import itertools
print([''.join(p) for p in itertools.combinations_with_replacement('abc', 3)])

>> ['aaaaa', 'aaaab', 'aaaac', 'aaabb', 'aaabc', 'aaacc', 'aabbb', 'aabbc', 'aabcc', 'aaccc', 'abbbb', 'abbbc', 'abbcc', 'abccc', 'acccc', 'bbbbb', 'bbbbc', 'bbbcc', 'bbccc', 'bcccc', 'ccccc']
```

Clearly, the list falls short by a long way.

I thought of partitioning e.g) 0As, 2Bs, 3Cs is 0+2+3. Finding exhaustively by hand gave an answer of 21 in under a minute in this example. In fact, I simplified the process by noticing the number of the third letter (say C, without loss of generality) depends on the combination of As and Bs, so I drew a table - red cross represents invalid combination since sum >= 5: [image: red cross represents invalid combination since sum >= 5] (As an aside, I wonder how this idea extends to N > 3; since from looking at the table, the square is cut in half...)

In order to transfer this 'algorithm' onto the computer, I've thought of somehow exploiting the symmetries - it kind of reminded me of Gray codes - but I cannot implement it correctly.

---

Are there any functions which will take care of this efficiently? Then I won't even have to (at least explicitly) call an anagram-checker function to compare inputs in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` literally solves what you're trying to accomplish? The return of the function is basically all the permutations without considering anagrams.

Comment: @YanOrestes well if you read my output above, quite clearly it does not. Could you expand upon why it worked for you?

Comment: What do you mean "quite clearly it does not". Please, give us an example of a string you think should be on the output and it is not.

Comment: @YanOrestes Sorry if I sound quite churlish, but the length of the output given by `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` above 'falls short by a long way' from 3^5 = 243 possibilities, since it is missing, for example, ACACB, BBABC, etc.

Comment: @geany1 But as far as I understand your question, your expected output should not have all 3^5 strings, since some of them are anagrams of each other. If you just want all 3^5 strings without the anagram-avoidance requirement, `itertools.product` does what you want.

Comment: Of course it's way below 3^5 if you don't want anagrams. It's missing ACACB because it already has `'AABCC'`, and it's missing BBABC because it already has `"ABBBC"`. I really don't get you, @geany1

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? It seems things are a bit unclear.

Comment: @YanOrestes aha yes I see what you mean now; pardon me, I had gravely misconceived my own output!

Comment: @kaya3 Thank-you for the clarification, and your extended reply below; indeed `products` was the method I was searching for, too fixated on finding all permutations first - for the wrong reasons of course

Comment: @AMC I have now realised my mistake, clarified by kaya3's answer.

Comment: @geany1 sorry for not being clear enough ;), I'm glad it's figured out now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **AIM:** I am trying to find the maximum length of a list comprising non-anagrams, of length N, each anagram-word consisting of a combination of 3 letters: 'A's, 'B's or 'C's.

Given this aim, your approach of generating all `3 ** 5` possible strings and then filtering out anagrams is not efficient. The number you want can be computed directly without actually generating any strings:

- Two strings are anagrams if and only if they have the same letter frequencies. For example, `ABCAB` is an anagram of `AABBC` because the letter frequencies are `{'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}` for both strings.
- The maximum possible length of a list containing no anagrams is therefore equal to the number of possible distinct frequency maps, where the keys are `'A', 'B', 'C'`, the values are non-negative integers, and the sum of the values is 5 (so that the string length is 5).
- This can be computed by counting the number of ways of partitioning a non-negative integer `n` into `k` parts, where the order of the parts matters, and a part is allowed to be 0.

Here's a recursive solution:

```py
from functools import lru_cache

# memoize since there are overlapping subproblems
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def count_partitions(n, k):
    if n < 0 or k < 0:
        raise ValueError()
    elif n == 0:
        return 1
    elif k <= 1:
        return k
    else:
        return sum(count_partitions(r, k - 1) for r in range(n + 1))
```

Example:

```py
>>> count_partitions(5, 3)
21
```

This agrees with `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`, which generates a list of 21 strings in this case, and it agrees with your calculation by hand.

---

In fact, we can go a bit further by framing the problem slightly differently: the number of ways of partitioning `n` into `k` parts is equivalent to the number of ways of inserting `k - 1` dividers between the `n` items. The result of placing the dividers is a string of length `n + k - 1`:

- In the example above, the dividers would be placed like `AA|BB|C`.
- Conversely, if we know where the two dividers are placed, like `..|..|.`, then we can fill in with letters to produce the string `AA|BB|C`.

So, we can reduce the problem to counting the number of ways of placing `k - 1` symbols `|` in a string of length `n + k - 1`. This is simply the binomial coefficient `binom(n + k - 1, k - 1)`:

```py
def binom(n, k):
    if n < 0 or k < 0 or k > n:
        return 0
    k = min(k, n - k)
    result = 1
    for a, b in zip(range(n, n - k, -1), range(1, k + 1)):
        result *= a
        result //= b
    return result

def count_partitions(n, k):
    return binom(n + k - 1, k - 1)
```